# Shrinking upper bound in limit

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Suppose $\{x_n\}\subset\mathbb{R}$ so that $x_n\to x$. Is it true that there exists some $N$ so that for all $n\ge N$, $|x_n-x|\le\frac{1}{2^n}$?

We have for each $\epsilon>0$, there exists $N_\epsilon$ so that $n\ge N_\epsilon$ implies $|x_n-x|\le\epsilon$. But this is a "static" upper bound (i.e. not shrinking in $n$). Can't remember how we get such a shrinking upper bound, if it is indeed possible.

Thanks in advance for any tips!

Comment: Try $x_n = 1/n$, $x=0$.

Comment: Try $x_n=2\cdot \frac1{2^n}$ and $x=0$.

Answer (score 1):

say I take the series $x_n = (1/10)^n$. We know $x_n \rightarrow 0$

say I have some $\epsilon$ for which there is such an $N$

You're saying $\forall n \geq N, (9/10)^n \leq 1/2^n$

However, we know that $(18^n \leq 10^n)$ is false.

I don't think *your* definition of convergence is equivalent to *the* definition of convergence, but you could define it and it probably has some nice properties.

Answer (score 1):

NO. Let $x=1$ and $x_n=1-2/2^n$.